# Inject $rootScope into factory works only partially

Tags: angularjs

In this plunker the factory gets a $rootScope injected.

The plunker is not from me.

When I inject the $rootScope into my own factories it does not work.

Why does it work in the plunker? Where is it written that I can inject the $rootScope in a factory?

http://plnkr.co/edit/2hoMTaloeqbgSe81VQLF?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('messageService', function($rootScope) {


alert($rootScope);
  var messenger = {
    messages: [],
    identity: 0,
    addMessage: function(text, caller) {

      this.identity +=1;
      var id = this.identity,
       message = {
        text: caller + text,
        id: id
      };

      this.messages.push(message);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('messageAdded');
    }
  };

  return messenger;
});

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope, messageService) {
  $scope.messages1 = messageService.messages;
  $scope.post = {
    text: ''
  };

  $scope.postMessage = function() {
    console.log($scope.post);
    messageService.addMessage($scope.text, "controller 1");
  };

  $scope.$on('messageAdded', function() {
    $scope.messages1 = messageService.messages;
  });
});



app.controller('Controller2', function($scope, messageService) {
  $scope.messages2 = messageService.messages;
  $scope.post = {
    text: ''
  };

  $scope.postMessage = function() {
    messageService.addMessage($scope.text, "controller 2");
  };

  $scope.$on('messageAdded', function() {
    $scope.messages2 = messageService.messages;
  });
});
```

THIS is just a sample code of myself and I have no idea why the $rootScope is not injected:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').factory('MyViewModel', function ($rootScope) {

    function MyViewModel(items ) {

        var self = this;
        self.items = items ;

     }


    return( MyViewModel);
});
```

Comment: Is your code exactly the same as the plunker?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Your code would be required to debug your issue.

Comment: From your sample code you never use `$rootScope`, how do you know it is not being injected?  Also `factory` will inject the value returned by the function, so if you inject `MyViewModel`, you will get the function `MyViewModel` declared inside the function you pass to `factory()` because that is what you return.  Maybe that's intented, it just seems strange and apt to lead to confusion to me.

Comment: I seem to have a general problem on my side I found out now. When I try to inject a factory it just does not work but I also get NO error so I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope` is definitely being injected here, but it will only happen when your service is instantiated.. which will only happen when you inject it into a controller or other service which is used on the page.

See below, variable added to `$rootScope`, inherited by controller:

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .factory('MyViewModel', function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.hello = 'Hello!';

    function MyViewModel(items) {

      var self = this;
      self.items = items;

    }

    return MyViewModel;
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function(MyViewModel) {
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{hello}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "... but it will only happen when your service is instantiated.. which will only happen when you inject it into a controller ..." This is not correct. When I return the MyViewModel declaration I am instantiating it for myself. There is not need to inject it anywhere to get the instance.